# UIManager.getColor returns null sometimes

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, japplet, uimanager

I have an applet that is generating a nullpointer exception at this line (but only sometimes) at load time:

(txtpnNoSeHa is a JEditorPane inside a class that extends JPanel. This panel is instantiated inside the applet constructor)

```
txtpnNoSeHa.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
```

called inside the constructor.

What I understand from this is that UIManager.getColor returns null sometimes maybe because some data has not been loaded (no swing panel has been shown or something similar)

The applet was designed with eclipse's window builder. How can I fix this? Any one can shed some light into this?

Comment: It was the look and feel, as MouseEvent suggested. Also the browser was loading a chached applet for some reason which had the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you had predicted, the `UIManager` is loaded as soon the first swing component is made visible. This may lead to `null` values. You can manually load the `UIManager` with this call **at the beginning of the `main` routine (or `init` for applets)**:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch(InvocationTargetException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: That is already at the init() of the applet. The panel in question is instantiated inside the applet constructor, which I would guess is called before init(). I will try moving it to the constructor.

Comment: @dabicho `Applet` or `JApplet`?  You could also try using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` to force it to initialise

Comment: It was JApplet. A previous (cached) version of the applet was being loaded, one which did not call setLookAndFeel. Thank you

Comment: @MouseEvent Sorry, butting in. `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` will load the UI defaults for that look and feel.  Calling that first would force the initalisation of the UIManagers values

Comment: @MouseEvent Don't forget that `JAppelt` is a Swing container, technically, it's already initialized a Swing component once it's created (before `init` is called)

Comment: hmmm @dabicho ... slightly astonished (though applets have their surprises :-) - would have expected the editor field to be null, that is throw the NPE, not a null color (it's perfectly valid to call comp.setBackground(null))

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, `JApplet` itself is a top level native component, but the `JRootPane` is...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue in the past, and I solved it by making every swing-related code to be run from the GUI-thread (EDT).

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```